# Watson Knowledge Catalogue missing the categories selection

Tags: watson-knowledge-catalog, data-governance

I'm trying to use WKC within my trial IBM Cloud account, I have the instance created but when I look to create the categories I am unable to see the "categories" option under the "governance" area within the menus. Specifically I only see under governance the following 3 options: Data dashboard, policy manager, business gloassary. Anyone know why I'm not able to see the full set?

Answer (score 0):

CPD menu items are dependent on the roles the current logged in user has.  If your exploring CPD, try using an ADMIN role.  If you are logged in as admin, ensure you have access to the "category" name in question.

Comment: Thank you.  I’m logged in as an admin and it’s the actual “categories” menu that I’m not able to see as opposed to a specific category that I may not have access to. Any further advice would be appreciated.

Comment: If you don't see HAMBURGER ICON --> Categories, then it would be a permission issue.  If you go to users, check the permissions for ADMIN.  I think you need the permission "Manage governance categories".   Here is a link to the permissions for v3.5.     https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cloud-paks/cp-data/3.5.0?topic=users-predefined-roles-permissions

Comment: Thanks @J Tuck, I read that link you shared, and it says ADMIN should have permissions to manage the catalogue, and checking it under Manage>Access>Roles  it looked correct. I think the problem may be this account use WKC years ago and holds a legacy catalogue. Per this IBM ref [link] (https://dataplatform.cloud.ibm.com/docs/content/wsj/governance/migrate-newui.html?audience=wdp), I can only see 3 options under Governance, rather than the full 9, my exact problem now. I followed their upgrade catalogue instructions, but the URL goes to a page where the upgrade btn is grayed out. Any ideas?

Comment: Hi @SamF - What version of CPD are you using and where is it deployed (e.g.:  Cloud, Private Data Center)?  Also, check to see if the Watson Knowledge Catalog is listed as an Enabled Service.  Go to the Service Catalog, Search for Watson Knowledge Catalog, and ensure you see the green Enabled box.

Comment: I'm using an IBM Cloud Subscription account, and so its running on the CP4DaaS platform. i.e in the Cloud Subscription account, I would create the WKC instance, and upon accessing the WKC instance it would load up the CP4DaaS environment (US). I believe your descriptions are for a CPD environment where WKC is deployed as an added service. That's not what I am doing here. If you see the link I posted above, its for CP4DaaS which is slightly different. Thanks!